# suppressing error max(size_t&, int) intelligently

Tags: c++

I have a lot of code that calls max(int, size_t);
Are there any smarter way to suppress this error?

It is kind of silly because it works with max(int, 0)

I am allowed to do this: `size_t i = 0;`

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  size_t i = 2;
  size_t m = std::max(i, size_t(2));
  // size_t m = std::max(i, 2); error: no matching function for call to 'max(size_t&, int)'

}
```

Comment: Aside from the cast (use `static_cast` not functional style cast), you have several options. As already suggested change `i` to int, Provide an explicit template parameter `max<size_t>(i, 2)` also you could use an unsigned long literal `max(i, 2UL)` (this assumes size_t is an unsigned long on your system).

Comment: C++ does not provide a literal suffix that would tell the compiler that `2` is supposed to have type `size_t`, so this cast is probably the best thing you can do (unless you want to turn that `2` into a named constant - another alternative). And functional or C-style cast for such purposes is more appropriate than unwieldy `static_cast`.

Comment: @AnT: Well, there's `size_t operator "" _st (unsigned long long x) { return x; }`. There's just no _predefined_ suffix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I prefer `std::max<size_t>(i, 2)`; it has a similar effect (actually, it's a bit better, because there's no explicit cast, that may silence more interesting warnings) and avoids cluttering the argument list.

An alternative is to write your own `max` that accepts arguments of different types and returns the "correct" common type (similarly as if it was done with a macro):

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto my_max(T t, U u) -> decltype(1?t:u){
    return t>u?t:u;
}
```